# CommonsXsdSchemaCollection xsd into a Jar/War - Spring Boot WS

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere

Good morning and happy new year.

I can not get files inside a WAR file, running in IBM Websphere, once it is compiled, the files are the path in \WEB-INF\classes\Schemas but I do not know how to get them from Java, in the project it works correctly (like this in the example, inside of resources)

```
    @Bean
    public XsdSchemaCollection consultarCollectorXsd() throws Exception {
        CommonsXsdSchemaCollection xsds = new CommonsXsdSchemaCollection(
                new ClassPathResource("/Schemas/Bancogalicia/Methods/ListarEstadosMensajeRequest-1.0.0.xsd"),
                new ClassPathResource("/Schemas/Bancogalicia/Methods/ListarEstadosMensajeResponse-1.0.0.xsd"),
                new ClassPathResource("/Schemas/Bancogalicia/Methods/ListarMensajesRequest-1.0.0.xsd"),
                new ClassPathResource("/Schemas/Bancogalicia/Methods/ListarMensajesResponse-1.0.0.xsd"),
                new ClassPathResource("/Schemas/Bancogalicia/Methods/ObtenerUltimoEstadoMensajeRequest-1.0.0.xsd"),
                new ClassPathResource("/Schemas/Bancogalicia/Methods/ObtenerUltimoEstadoMensajeResponse-1.0.0.xsd")
        );
        xsds.setInline(true); 
        return xsds;
    }
```

Comment: How exactly do you need to "get" the files? If you just need a handle to a URL (or InputStream), they'd be visible through a ClassLoader.getResource() or getResourceAsStream() call - WEB-INF/classes gets added as an entry on the WAR class path, so getResource("Schemas/path/to/the.xsd") would get you the URL.

Comment: I need to obtain these files to generate the wsdl signature that will expose the web service, without being able to obtain these files, I will not be able to expose the signature. Since Spring WS is Contract First, and the CommonsXsdSchemaCollection contructor only accepts 1 or more Resource (Resource... resource), getResource() return a URL